# Chef guard multiple resources with single not_if

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

When using chef, I only want to execute a sequence of resources if a certain condition is fulfilled. Currently, I have to add the `not_if` guard to each resource individually. Is there a way to wrap multiple resources inside with a single not_if guard like so:

```
wrap_resources do
  service 'my-service'
  package 'my-package'
  not_if certain_condition
end
```

And I do not want to use that nasty notify!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution for at compile time condition:

```
if !certain_condition
  service 'my-service'
  package 'my-package'
end
```

Recipes allow pure ruby, you can just skip defining those resources in your recipe with a simple if block.

---

According to your example, you're looking for a LWRP or from chef 12.5 [`custom_resource`](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html)

The syntax is near the same, LWRP use two files (resource and provider) where custom_resource use only one.

The idea behind this is to create a new resource which will do some tests at converge time and then run it's inner resources if needed. The LWRP/custom_resource inner resources are run in a separate context.

I.e:

my_cookbook/resources/wrapper.rb

```
property :name, RubyType, default: 'value'

default_action: run

action :run do
  service 'my-service'
  package 'my-package'
end
```

my_cookbook/recipes/default.rb

```
my_cookbook_wrapper 'service and package' do
  not_if lazy { certain_condition }
end
```

Beware if you're using `-` in your cookbook name, this char is not allowed for Ruby Classes and is replaced by a `_` if found.

Comment: Will this also work if I need the condition to be computed lazily?

Comment: No, as it will be evaluated at recipe compilation time. If you need to wrap several resources an use only one guard, use a LWRP or the new custom_resource way to write them. Updating the answer

Comment: Another approach is to just rethink your not_if so that it doesn't have to be lazy and so you can use the simpler compile time definition.  What you are stating by the fact that you want them to be lazy is that you depend on other resources running first, but those resources also depend on conditions as to when they run.  If you walk backwards you should be able to arrive at a condition you can evaluate at compile time.

Comment: It also may be easier to structure this through notifications so that the prior resource firing causes the actions to happens.

Comment: lamont I think you forgot to ping @adracus ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following:

```
unless certain_condition
  service 'my-service'
  package 'my-package'
end
```

So that you don't need to use a negative statement. Makes it a little more cleaner!